# is there any way to send a message using the Odoo mailing list?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I work on an Odoo module where I import the mailing class mailing list, this mailing list sends me emails and I want it to send me the phone numbers I added to the contact class. Have an idea of how I can proceed please

Comment: Maybe can this [Odoo forum's question](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-add-more-information-to-internal-note-emails-sent-from-project-tasks-customer-project-deadline-145138) help you?